# Divided Circular Progress Bar

Tags: flutter

I need to achieve something like this
[image]

I've tried various dependencies like flutter_step_indicator and syncfusion but I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: i may go for `svg` and simple widget, also you can choose `customPainter` instead of using `svg`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you elaborate, please?

Comment: lets create a stack widget, then on top level place background `greyImage`, if you want it animated, we can use AnimationRotate / `Transform`, then on bottom level of stack place those text using `Align`/`Positioned` widget. hope you get it, else you can share the `svg` of backGorund image,

Comment: @AlexStroia can you explain the progress? I think the division is meant to be changed dynamically with time.

Comment: i think you like to animate that middle grey circle, then you can use customPainter, but i need to see prototype, what and how do you like to animate., can you share a gif or something of that animation that you like to archive